# Проблема с автоматическим масштабированием текста EditView

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-widgets

Возникла проблема с уменьшением текста по мере достижения границ EditText.

```
 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:paddingLeft="50dp"
        android:paddingRight="50dp"

    style="@style/SignText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@+id/image_view"

    android:gravity="center"

    android:maxLines="2"
    android:textSize="60sp"
    app:autoSizeStepGranularity="150dp"
    app:autoSizeTextType="uniform"
    app:autoSizeMaxTextSize="60dp"
    app:autoSizeMinTextSize="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:targetApi="o"
    tools:text="welcome"
    tools:textColor="@color/cyan" />
```

Comment: какая проблема, конкретнее?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от него.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно использовать библиотеку либо самому что-то слепить. [Вот библиотека](https://github.com/ViksaaSkool/AutoFitEditText) которая вам должна подойти. Подключаем в `build.gradle`:

```
implementation 'com.github.ViksaaSkool:AutoFitEditText:53238e2d29'
```

добавляем в разметку данное поле для ввода:

```
<com.autofit.et.lib.AutoFitEditText
            android:id="@+id/rET"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/primary"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:hint="@string/hint"
            android:isScrollContainer="false"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine|textNoSuggestions"
            android:maxLength="240"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textColorHint="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="90sp" />
```

делаем все необходимые настройки в активности:

```
//in onCreate in Activity/Fragment
        mAutoFitEditText.setEnabled(true);
        mAutoFitEditText.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        mAutoFitEditText.setFocusable(true);
        mAutoFitEditText.setEnableSizeCache(false);
        //might cause crash on some devices
        mAutoFitEditText.setMovementMethod(null);
        // can be added after layout inflation;
        mAutoFitEditText.setMaxHeight(330);
        //don't forget to add min text size programmatically
        mAutoFitEditText.setMinTextSize(60f);

        AutoFitEditTextUtil.setNormalization(this, mRootView, mAutoFitEditText);
```

и у вас будет масштабирование текста в поле для ввода. Вот есть еще подобная [библиотека](https://github.com/txusballesteros/AutosizeEditText) и [туториал](https://viksaaskool.wordpress.com/2014/11/16/using-auto-resize-to-fit-edittext-in-android/)

Comment: Благодарю! Все работает почти идеально, кроме одной небольшой проблемы: 
текст в поле EditText масштабируется до максимального, и не получается распределить его в  несколько строчек, мне необходимо их две.

Comment: уточните пожалуйста, а то немного непонятно)

Comment: только что решила проблему, спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Рад что у вас все получилось)